# How can I validate that two chart images are identical?

Tags: computer-vision

I want to write a function to compare two images and tell whether they contain the same chart or not. For example, the charts shown below:
[image]

[image]

These two images are of the same chart. However, the charts have different colors, different sizes, different backgrounds, and won't be easily aligned together. How can I write a, preferably a javascript, function that can whether two passed images are of the same chart or not?

In other words, I want a function that tell whether the two chart line could be aligned together or not regardless of the actual points on the axes.

Comment: implement something that recognizes these charts and turns them back into approximations of data. then you can compare the data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have no idea how to implement this. Any recommendations?

Comment: depends on how bad your input pictures are. first I'd find the grid, then extract the tick labels, then follow the chart lines and turn that into values, perhaps using the bulbous sample markers instead of the connecting lines. -- or throw feature matching at it, but that needn't work too well